# How to store response in value?

Tags: php

i have json format  {error:No billing history available}

how to store **error** value in variable.

i have no idea how to store **error** value in variable

**i want to store {error} value in variable**

Comment: Can you post your code that you have tried?

Comment: i simple use $arr['error'] but it can not work

Comment: @ViralPatelViralPatelPHP That's because it's json and not an array. You have to use `json_decode` first. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use json_decode to convert the string result into an array.

Take care, you have to set the correct parameter , otherwise you get an object back.

```
$json_result = '{"error": "No billing history available"}';
$result_array = json_decode($json_result, TRUE);

echo $result_array['error'];
```

That should cover your need.

Maybe im wrong, because next time be a bit more precise, please and provide more code you've tried.